# Анонимный интерфейс c#

Tags: c#

Есть интерфейс

```
intefrace IMy {
    void say(String msg);
}
```

Есть класс

```
class My {
    IMy iMy;
    public My() {
        iMy = (str) = > Console.WriteLine(str); //ошибка
        iMy.say("Text");
    }
}
```

На строке с `//ошибка` мне пишет

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type IMy, because it is not a
>   delegate type

Что мне надо изменить в коде, чтобы я мог инициализировать переменную `iMy` моим способом?

**P.S.** сам пишу на `java`, и там такая конструкция работает. Какая аналогичная конструкция в `c#`?

Comment: нельзя создать экземпляр интерфейса  https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173156.aspx

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Какая тогда аналогичная контрукция будет в шарпе?

Comment: только создавая класс реализующий этот интерфейс, либо вообще убрать интерфейс и работать с делегатами

Comment: @Andrew Bystrov а просто реализовать его нельзя?

Comment: @ValeraKvip у меня будет 2 инстанса интерфейса IMy и у каждого должна быть своя реализация. Хотелось бы красиво через лямбду это сделать.

Comment: @Andrew Bystrov да, уже ответ дали, использовать делегат.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по примеру использования вместо интерфейса в данном случае можно использовать делегат [Action<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx), например так

```
class My {
    Action<string> iMy;
    public My() {
        iMy = (str) => Console.WriteLine(str); //ок
        iMy("Text");
    }
}
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что я могу изменить свой интерфейс iMy следующим образом public delegate void IMy<in String>(String msg) и поведение будет тоже самое, что и с Action<T>?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov, да, за исключением того, что в этом случае _<in String>_ будет являться именем типа, а не ограничением: `только String` и при использовании все равно надо будет указывать `iMy<string>`, чтобы не указывать нужно просто убрать эту часть: `public delegate void IMy(String msg);`

Comment: Благодар, очень помогли

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы класс обладал заданным интерфейсом, он должен наследовать этот интерфейс и реализовать методы, которые объявлены в интерфейсе. Ниже показана демонстрационная программа

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Simple_interface
{
    interface IMy
    {
        void Say(string msg);
    }

    class A1: IMy
    {
        public void Say( string msg ) => Console.WriteLine( nameof( A1 ) + ": " + msg );
    }

    class A2: IMy
    {
        public void Say(string msg) => Console.WriteLine(nameof( A2 ) + ": " + msg);
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<IMy> list = new List<IMy> { new A1(), new A2() };

            foreach (var item in list) item.Say("is called");
        }
    }
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
A1: is called
A2: is called
```

Имейте в виду, что данный кол будет компилироваться для версии C# 6. Вы можете ознакомиться с новыми возможностями C#, посмотрев это [видео](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-2015-Enterprise-Videos/Whats-New-in-CSharp-6#time=0s)

Comment: Меня интересовал ( как оказалось) именно делегат, а не интерфейс. Но спасибо за ответ.